# trying to create automatic timestamp for new records

Tags: php, mysql

here's the table:

```
   CREATE TABLE `obits` (
  `pid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `surname` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `middlename` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `maiden` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `presuf` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `birth` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `death` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `obitdate` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `obitsource` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `sourcepage` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `obittext` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `DateCreated` DATETIME COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT(GETDATE())
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

here is the error I'm getting: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(GETDATE())
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci' at line 14 (line 14 is the datecreated line)

I probably missed something really simple but for the life of me I don't know what. Thank you for any/all help. This table was fine before I tried to re-create it with the datecreated line.

Comment: you're trying to use a function inside table creation? `DEFAULT()` isn't a function it's an "option". http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html

Comment: As a side-note, is `GETDATE()` a function in MySQL? Isn't it `NOW()`?

Comment: `GETDATE()` is of MSSQL not MySql.

Comment: `GETDATE()` isn't even a MySQL function, it's used in MSSQL https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx - which RDBMS are you really using? or are you not paying attention to commenters here?

Comment: okay so that identifies the problem but doesn't explain how to fix it

Comment: that guy gave you an answer that you're right; it didn't explain it where I made a comment about it. So... question solved or not? and which RDBMS are you using here?

Comment: um no? it didn't. as i said, DateCreated DATETIME COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP gave me 'Invalid default value for 'DateCreated''

Comment: well he's the one with all those upvotes so I'll take a back seat on this one, and you didn't tell us which RDBMS you're using.

Comment: mysql hence why mssql getdate didn't work apparently

Comment: @aloeveraking24 what version of MySql are you using? Prior to MySql 5.6.5 you cannot do a default of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` unless the column type is `TIMESTAMP`

Comment: that is a very good question that I do not know the answer to! let me investigate. unless you know how I can find out. Using phpMyAdmin SQL Dump version 4.5.3.1 whatever this means

Comment: aha! that fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You can't use a function to fill default values in MySql, except CURRENT_TIMESTAMP for TIMESTAMP columns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/data-type-defaults.html). Prior to version 5.6.5, you must use TIMESTAMP.

```
DateCreated TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

After version 5.6.5, you are able to use DATETIME columns with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as default value.

Comment: Why should they "try"? Unless the OP doesn't care for it. Personally, an explanation would be more beneficial for all.

Comment: `DateCreated` DATETIME COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL     DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Comment: oops    `DateCreated` DATETIME COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP gave me 'Invalid default value for 'DateCreated''

Comment: Answer updated with explanation.